# Threshold value for Cluster after document similarity

Tags: machine-learning, standard-deviation, mean, threshold

I have N documents.

I have found out cosine similarity between all documents. T = (N*(N-1)/2)

Because docSim between a document with itself is 1.

Now, I have one query and I want to find out all documents which are similar to it. I don't want to rank it but cluster it based on threshold value.

Here is how I calculated threshold value.

```
Average: Mean of all(T) cosineSimilarities
Average(T) + alpha*standardDeviation(T)
```

How do you find the parameter alpha?
I found this formula here

```
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Determination_of_threshold_for_cosine_similarity_score
```

Is there any other way to find out threshold?

Some suggestions on formula might improve my cluster.
Thank you